# How to choose the resistors for UC3906

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I would like to build a battery charger with my UC3906 IC. I found a lot of data-sheets, application note, etc. but nothing that comprehensively explain how to choose the values of the resistors. I would expect a "few lines guide" of the form "for a n cells 12V battery, choose R1, R2, etc. such and such." But I found nothing like this. Can someone help?
In my case, I have a 6 cells 12V lead acid battery (cells in series apparently, capacity not specified), but it would be nice if the answer be general and valid for any type of lead acid battery.

Comment: Have you read this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc3906.pdf and figure 2

Comment: Yes, of course, this is the standard data-sheet. But they do not explain how to choose I_D,  V_F, V_OC, V_T, I_max and I_T.

Comment: Obviously you did not read Fig 2,5 , all batteries are not the same. Pretending so, may invalidate some warranties.

Comment: But this is the object of the question: how to choose these parameters according to the battery (number of cells, capacitance etc.). At least, I would expect some typical recommendations.

Comment: Lead-acid cells are nominally 2 Volts, so a 12 Volt battery would have 6 cells in series.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Indeed, I see 3 pairs of cells (I believe). I will edit the question.

Comment: It is always best to match battery to similar supplier specs on how to optimize charge profile.  http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_the_lead_acid_battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the spec for the BQ24450. It's the exact same IC, same die - just changed the name for some reason - much better explanations. Also, if you have a problem initially getting the IC into the right state when first powering on (i.e bulk charge ), try putting a 10uf cap or so across the sense resistor that goes to pin 13 (the bottom resistor in the output voltage divider). Or you can put a reset switch across that same resistor - just press the switch after powering on to start the the bulk charge mode. Took me a while to figure that out - the circuit was going directly into the float state - skipping over bulk charge and over voltage. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: For me, this post is old now, but yes, I'm sure this will help someone.

Comment: Thanks for the BQ24450 reference.

Comment: Also, thanks for the tip regarding the cap across the sense resistor. I used a 3uf and it solved the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!
I had the same issue : when power on, the BQ24450 goes to float mode (13.xV). Adding 1uF (I had only such value) across the Rd resistor (from Fig.8) resolve the problem. But adding a switch across the Rd resistor and pressing it, stops the bulk charge mode.

Comment: Hello. As a new contributor, I just want to inform you that if you are satisfied with some answer, don't forget to upvote it. Also, upvote the question if it helped you.